# Magento 2 override minicart.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento2, template, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I'm trying to override minicart.phtml file from `Magento2\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml` to my custom module

```
Magento2\vendor\XXXX\YYYY\view\frontend\templates\cart\minicart.phtml
```

I copied everything from default.xml from `Magento2\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\default.xml` to my custom module layout `Magento2\vendor\XXXX\YYYY\view\frontend\layout\default.xml` with my custom template file path. Below is the layout file with Updated template path,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="XXXXXX_YYYYYY::cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here you can see my updated template path,

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="XXXXXX_YYYYYY::cart/minicart.phtml">
```

Then I cleared cache, upgrade, static content deploy .. Then I'm getting below error in store front.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return { data:getCartItems(),as:'item'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return $parent.getRegion($parent.getItemRenderer(item.product_type)) }"
Message: Cannot read property 'simple' of undefined
    at UiClass.getItemRenderer (minicart.js:139)
    at foreach (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:93)
```

I put some logs in minicart.phtml and its loading . It's seems like minicart js is not loading properly...Any idea .?

**Update:1**

I put some logs in `minicart.js` and it's loading. So I think it might have problem with `content.html`. I'm using Magento 2.2.5  with default Luma theme

Comment: Just to inform you. Using Magento 2.3.0. Not using any custom theme. And I am able to override minicart.phtml using the same code. I am not getting any error.

Comment: @Vky Thanks for your comment. But in my case it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The way to you has tried to override the `minicart.phtml` is wrong.

As you want to override the `minicart.phtml` So, you need to change only using the  below code

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" template="XXXXXX_YYYYYY::cart/minicart.phtml"  after="logo"/>
```

add this code `default.xml`.

There are not need to copy all code from `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\default.xml` to `\vendor\XXXX\YYYY\view\frontend\layout\default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" template="XXXXXX_YYYYYY::cart/minicart.phtml"  after="logo"/>   
    </body>
</page>
```

***Note that work on vendor folder is not good idea.***

Comment: Thanks for the post. This is the first thing I was tried, but got the same error so I was trying with adding all the code in xml file. Now I solved by without overriding the template (different logic)..

Answer (score 1):

You can override `minicart.phtml` file using below code in your module's `default.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::cart/minicart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

As `setTemplate` method is deprecated, you can use new method:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName::cart/minicart.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Flush cache.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I tried this also, got Error like   "invalid action 'setTemplate' in your layout..."   Now I solved by without overriding the template (different logic)..

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below method to override minicart.phtml

Go to :

```
\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\
```

and copy minicart.phtml file

After keep that file here

```
\Your_Vendor\Your_Theme\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\
```

Clear cache and check...

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I have to override in a module itself.